# CMD command in Dockerfile doesn't execute when I run docker build

Tags: cmd.exe, docker

I'm running Docker on Windows 10.

I have a simple Dockerfile:

```
# Use an exisisting docker image as base
FROM alpine

# Download and install a dependency
RUN apk add --update redis

# Tell the image what to do when it starts as a container
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

However when I run it in command prompt

```
docker build .
```

CMD part never executes and it shows only two steps instead of 3 in the logs:

[image]

While in the tutorial I'm following the third step, the CMD part does get executed:

[image]

My Docker version is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supposed to be run. `CMD` defines the default command to run when you execute the container, not when you build it. You'll see the value set when you inspect the image.

Note there is only one value for `CMD`, so setting it again overrides the previous value, and it can be set when the container is created. With `docker run`, that override is anything specified after the image name. E.g. `docker run --rm busybox:latest echo hello` overrides the default `/bin/sh` `CMD` with `echo hello`.

For more details, see the Dockerfile reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right. It seems that the CMD command has been removed from being logged as part of the build process. In the previous versions od Docker command would be reported as a part of a build process. Now Docker no longer reports it.

Comment: Also for reference, if someone runs into this issue (while learning from an older tutorial or something) and keeps on wondering why CMD doesn't appear in the logs similar/same question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092589/docker-cmd-command-not-running